# git create remote branch without clobbering any existing branch

Tags: git, race-condition

I want to create a development branch both locally and remotely without accidentally interfering with anyone else's development branches. Creating a local branch is easy and does not suffer from any race conditions, but creating a remote branch safely is tricky.

Say I want to create a branch called `cleanup`, but someone else may have had the same idea and created their own branch named `cleanup` just before me. If I simply `git push --set-upstream origin cleanup`, maybe it will create a new remote branch, or maybe it will fast forward an already existing branch.

I want `git push ...` to fail if the remote branch already exists so I can choose a different branch name.

I'm already aware of several imperfect solutions, like `git fetch` and then *quickly* pushing; this is still subject to race conditions. Or doing a `git push`, noticing whether the remote branch existed in the output of the command, and then trying to recover from the undesirable situation; this is way messy and subject to even worse race conditions during the recovery. It's also possible to use `git push --force-with-lease` in various ways to do similar things, but the closest I came to a solution to my problem was refusing to create a branch instead of fast fowarding, which is the opposite of my goal.

*UPDATE*: Ideally a solution would have no algorithmic complexity dependency on the number of files in the tree or the length of the git history. Solutions that require making a new clone of the repo or deleting and re-checking out all files in the working tree are unacceptable.

Comment: If you've got a posterboard repo going why not just put `youruserid/` on the front of the branches you're posting?  Branch names are _strictly_ repo-local, any correspondence among repos is a matter of collaboration and convenience.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a posterboard repo. I'm in a typical centralized-origin situation where many developers clone the repo from github and have push access.

Comment: Why would you ever name a branch "cleanup" unless you have some common project named "cleanup"? You should work with your team to develop some naming standards for branches, such as incorporating issue numbers into them or similar. I'm assuming you're not just doing things all willy-nilly as git, nor any other vcs, have a way of handling "WE'RE JUST DOING STUFF RANDOMLY".

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Actually, Git does have a way of handling WIP stuff and low-odds experiments and the like, that's one of its rjeally stellar features: don't push it to for-publication repos.  Repos are peers and it's easy to collaborate but nobody needs to see the notes on your desk or the extended-undo-buffer commits in your repo.

Comment: Agreed, but if I create a branch named X and try to push that to a remote, if that branch name already exists in that remote there is no way I can persuade that remote to create another branch named X, it's going to be either the same branch (that I modify) or I cannot push.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Sure you can: `git push origin X:Lasse/X`.  Branch names are repo-local. Your repo is yours, you decide what goes on in it and you're not constrained by what happens in anybody else's repo.  Git makes it easy to set up the obvious correspondences but they're not mandatatory, for reasons that become more and more apparent as you start figuring out what that makes possible.  Whoever runs `origin` has complete control over what goes on there, too, vettnig refnames and what gets pushed to them is easy.

Comment: That was not the case that the question detailed, which included `git push --set-upstream origin cleanup`, which would name the upstream branch `cleanup` as well. Obviously if you make sure there is no naming collision then *there will be no naming collision*. If you create personal branches then I assume the branches will be... well... personal.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I don't think it's a good idea to leave bad premises unaddressed.

Comment: @jthill Not sure what you mean by that comment.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it's simple: OP is presuming the approach he's taking is the best way to address his situation.  It might be my failure, but I can't imagine any situation where so many people inventing branch names for a common repo  that collisions while pushing to them are a real possibility is the right situation to use CDMA on branch name invention.  So I address what in my experience are common misconceptions i.e. bad premises of people who come up with the solutions they're having such trouble implementing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function git-new-branch() {
    # usage: git-new-branch branchname
    git push origin $(git commit-tree -m "" $(git mktree <&-) <&-):refs/heads/$1 || return 1
    git checkout -b $1
    git push --set-upstream --force-with-lease origin $1
}
```

### Explanation

`git mktree` and `git commit-tree` read stdin, so use `<%-` to close stdin for those processes.

The `git mktree` is idempotent and prints a sha1 of an empty tree.

The `git commit-tree` makes an empty commit with the empty tree, and importantly the commit has no parents. The `git commit-tree` also prints a sha1, but it is not idempotent. The commit has your `user.name` and a timestamp. Furthermore, this commit goes into the `.git` directory as an orphan commit. Orphaned commits will eventually be garbage collected by `git` automatically; see `git help gc`. The `-m ""` means the commit message will be empty. But none of this matters too much, because this commit will be used once and immediately abandoned.

The first `git push` pushes the empty commit to the branch name you give. If the branch already exists, it is guaranteed to be rejected, because the empty commit has no parents, therefore pushing it can't possibly cause a fast forward. (And since the commit is generated anew on each invocation, there's no chance that the commit is already in the remote repo anywhere.)

The `|| return 1` will abort the function if the command fails.

There's no error checking on the `git checkout -b` command. This function assumes you don't yet have a local branch with the given name.

The second `git push` uses `--force-with-lease`, which means the remote branch will only be updated if it's still what we thought it was, which is the empty commit we just pushed.

### Credits

Thanks to answers from o11c and jthill for inspiration for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, you've got a posterboard repo going, where everybody pushes WIP commits that might be worth sharing or whatever.  There are other workflows that don't lead to questions like yours, running off pull requests and the like, but all workflows have their downsides.  Scaling can be a downside for posterboard repos, but namespace collisions aren't hard to avoid.

Branch names are repo-local.  Any correspondence among repos is strictly a matter of convenience and collaboration; it's often convenient to use the same names, but it's also often convenient to have a local name for a branch, or not to share it at all.

Going on what you're saying here, so it is here.

```
git push -u origin featureb:thejoshwolfe/featureb
```

when pushing your `featureb` branch the first time, I'd push `:jthill/featureb` etc.  Your repo is yours, branches in your repos track whatever upstream branches you say they do.

edit: Git will, by default, refuse pushes that don't include all currently-referenced history for a branch.  If two people try to push conflicting histories to a single branch name, git will reject whichever comes in second.  You can use `--force-with-lease` to do safe force pushes in high-volume grand-central-station repos, but there are other ways to avoid that problem.

To reserve-or-fail a new branch name, do

```
git push origin $(git commit-tree -m - `:|git mktree` <&-):refs/heads/newbranch
```

and if that works the name's yours, you can safely force-push over it now with a `git push -u origin +newbranch`.

Comment: thanks for a solution to the problem. I would have accepted this answer if you didn't spend the first half of your response avoiding the question.

Comment: Fair enough, no complaints. People tend to ask how to implement the solutions they've already chosen for the situation they're in.  I'm on the fence about what you're doing so I offered an alternative and some background along with an answer to he question as asked, guilty as charged on burying the lead.   Good job and +1 on the answer you wrote and accepted, it deserves it.

Answer (score -1):

Create the branch with a new root commit. Since root commits don't have any parents, it can't be a fast-forward.

Then use `--force-with-lease` to replace the temporary root commit with the real commit you want.

Edit: self-contained script to demonstrate that this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# make this script idempotent
rm -rf /tmp/git-remote-demo/
mkdir -p /tmp/git-remote-demo/
cd /tmp/git-remote-demo/

# create a new "remote" repo and a couple of clones.
# (i.e what most real-world repos already look like)
git init --bare ./remote.git/
echo
git clone ./remote.git user1/
(cd user1/;
echo 'this is a readme' > readme.txt
git add readme.txt
git commit -m 'initial commit'
echo 'it has been modified' >> readme.txt
git add readme.txt
git commit -m 'modify readme'
git push origin master
)
echo
git clone ./remote.git user2/
echo

# then each user does work on their part
for user in user1 user2
do
(
    cd "$user"
    echo "I am $user"

    # work on a feature
    echo "work by $user" > readme.txt
    git add readme.txt
    git commit -m "work by $user"

    # interesting part starts here
    empty_tree="$(true | git mktree)"

    temp_commit="$(git commit-tree "$empty_tree" -m "temp commit for $user")"
    # demonstrate that this works even for race conditions
    git push origin "$temp_commit":refs/heads/race || echo "race push failed for $user"
    # demonstrate that this works normally
    { git push origin "$temp_commit":refs/heads/full && git push origin master:full --force-with-lease; } || echo "full push failed for $user"
    echo
)
done

echo "Remote branches:"
(cd remote.git && git branch -av)
```

Comment: showing some steps would be nice. when i tried to do this, i got an error `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:` when trying to switch out of the empty commit back to my dev branch.

Comment: This will in no way bypass the naming collision of using a branch name someone else has already used.,

Comment: @thejoshwolfe that sounds like you didn't create an empty commit properly, see script for how to cleanly create a unique empty commit.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen This answers the question the OP actually asked: to *notify* if there is a branch name collision.